# How to make a list from a tabular text using VIM

Tags: vim

I have some text like this:

```
UUU F      CUU L      AUU I      GUU V
UUC F      CUC L      AUC I      GUC V
UUA L      CUA L      AUA I      GUA V
UUG L      CUG L      AUG M      GUG V
```

And I want to make it look like this:

```
'UUU': 'F',
'CUU': 'L',
'AUU': 'I',
'GUU': 'V',
'UUC': 'F',
'CUC': 'L',
'AUC': 'I',
'GUC': 'V',
'UUA': 'L',
'CUA': 'L',
'AUA': 'I',
'GUA': 'V',
'UUG': 'L',
'CUG': 'L',
'AUG': 'M',
'GUG': 'V',
```

What is the best way to do it using VIM?

Comment: What have you tried? I also have no idea how you got from the start to the end text.

Comment: I'm newbie to Vim. I actually did it manually in gedit, but it must be a better way.

Comment: There is a better way but The input text does not match the output text. For instance there are 16 groups in the input but only 8 in the output. The first line of the output is UUC the input was UUU.

Comment: It was my mistake while making this question. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this in vim. One way is to use a substitution.

```
:%s/\(\w\w\w\) \(\w\)\_s*/'\1': '\2',\r/g
```

This looks for three letters followed by a space followed by another letter and place the first three letter in the first capture group (`\1`) and the single letter into the second capture group (`\2`). We also consume all trailing whitespace (including newlines with `\_s*`).

This is then replaced with `'\1': '\2',\r` where the `\r` is the newline.

Comment: It worked! I'll learn more about regular expresions and Vim. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is less intimidating (and easier to troubleshoot) if you break it into chunks. First you merge the columns into one single column by replacing multiple spaces with a line break:

`:%s/ \{2,}/\r/g`

```
UUU F
CUU L
AUU I
```

Then you surround the strings with single quotes:

`:%s/\w\+/'&'/g`

```
'UUU' 'F'
'CUU' 'L'
'AUU' 'I'
```

Add the comma at the end:

`:%s/$/,`

```
'UUU' 'F',
'CUU' 'L',
'AUU' 'I',
```

Add the colon:

`%s/' /': /`

```
'UUU': 'F',
'CUU': 'L',
'AUU': 'I',
```

... and you're set.